# How to access dynamically created input tag value in typescript file

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<div *ngFor="let task of arrayList">
<input id="task.fieldName" *ngIf="task.key === 'Others'" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

The input filed is a dynamically created field based on a condition, so how can i access the input value in typescript file.

I know how to access one input field name using @ViewChild. Is there any other method available for accessing dynamically created element(s) value?

Comment: Access when? Access for what purpose?

Comment: If you can use ngModel then I think it will be easier. You can directly access that object.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngFor="let task of arrayList">
  <input [(ngModel)]="values[task.key]" id="task.fieldName" *ngIf="task.key === 'Others'" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

```
class MyComponent {
  values = {};
}
```

This way `values` will contain the values added into the inputs like

```
{key1: 'abc', key2: 'def', ... }
```